# Kernel bug swap

Tags: kernel, swap, bug-reporting

Ubuntu 18 bugged and I noticed this messages in my `/var/log/syslog` file:

I often have issues with the `swap`, the `kswapd0` process running and taking a lot of CPU. What can I do to prevents all these bugs?

```
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113350] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113352] kernel BUG at /build/linux-hwe-uR14Ux/linux-hwe-5.3.0/mm/zswap.c:1166!
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113359] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113362] CPU: 1 PID: 5908 Comm: gnome-shell Tainted: P           OE     5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113364] Hardware name: LENOVO 80X7/LNVNB161216, BIOS 4MCN33WW(V2.05) 07/19/2018
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113369] RIP: 0010:zswap_frontswap_load+0x1b0/0x1c0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113372] Code: e8 75 d5 b7 00 41 89 c7 41 83 ac 24 98 12 00 00 01 48 8b 43 28 48 8b 73 30 48 8b 38 e8 e9 c4 03 00 45 85 ff 0f 84 12 ff ff ff <0f> 0b e8 c9 6a e1 ff 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113374] RSP: 0000:ffffb6dd0332fb48 EFLAGS: 00010282
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113376] RAX: ffffffffa14bfd60 RBX: ffff966c9e6d73b8 RCX: ffff966b85e76f4a
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113377] RDX: ffff966e01154000 RSI: ffff966b85e76e80 RDI: ffff966e37cc0000
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113379] RBP: ffffb6dd0332fb88 R08: 0000000000000c98 R09: 0000000000000112
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113380] R10: ffff966b85e76fef R11: ffff966e01155000 R12: ffff966de1dd0000
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113381] R13: ffff966e2f4b2658 R14: ffff966e2f4b2650 R15: 00000000ffffffea
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113383] FS:  00007f432c805ac0(0000) GS:ffff966e39c80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113385] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113386] CR2: 00005652fccc45e0 CR3: 0000000253542006 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113387] Call Trace:
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113392]  __frontswap_load+0x73/0xd0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113394]  swap_readpage+0x74/0x1f0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113397]  swap_cluster_readahead+0x1db/0x2b0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113400]  swapin_readahead+0x60/0x4e0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113402]  ? find_get_entry+0x58/0x160
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113404]  ? swapin_readahead+0x60/0x4e0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113406]  ? pagecache_get_page+0x2c/0x2b0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113409]  do_swap_page+0x31b/0x990
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113411]  ? do_swap_page+0x31b/0x990
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113414]  __handle_mm_fault+0x77a/0x1230
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113416]  ? __cgroup_account_cputime+0x28/0x30
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113419]  handle_mm_fault+0xcb/0x210
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113423]  __do_page_fault+0x2a1/0x4d0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113425]  do_page_fault+0x2c/0xe0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113429]  page_fault+0x34/0x40
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113431] RIP: 0033:0x7f43298735e8
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113433] Code: 70 48 83 fa 40 72 47 0f 10 06 0f 10 4e 10 0f 10 56 20 0f 10 5e 30 0f 10 64 16 f0 0f 10 6c 16 e0 0f 10 74 16 d0 0f 10 7c 16 c0 <0f> 11 07 0f 11 4f 10 0f 11 57 20 0f 11 5f 30 0f 11 64 17 f0 0f 11
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113434] RSP: 002b:00007ffecca60188 EFLAGS: 00010246
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113436] RAX: 00005652fccc45e0 RBX: 0000000000000005 RCX: 000000000000003f
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113437] RDX: 0000000000000040 RSI: 00005652f22f6cd0 RDI: 00005652fccc45e0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113439] RBP: 0000000000004d40 R08: 00005652f22f6bd0 R09: 00005652fccbf8a0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113440] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 00005652fccbf8a0
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113441] R13: 00005652f22f6bd0 R14: 0000000000000040 R15: 0000000000000000
Mar 18 19:55:14 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB kernel: [67157.113443] Modules linked in: btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs libcrc32c vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) rfcomm vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock vmw_vmci ccm thunderbolt hidp cmac bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio nls_iso8859_1 hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_als hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio hid_sensor_custom nvidia_uvm(OE) 8250_dw hid_multitouch wacom hid_sensor_hub mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_rawmidi intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_seq ath10k_pci ath10k_core intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof serio_raw ath snd_seq_device snd_timer mac80211 snd
```

**EDIT**

As advised by @heynnema I have removed the zswap feature and unfortunately my Ubuntu 18 crashed yesterday before 21:36.

My desktop is really charged:
[image: Screenshot Ubuntu]

And using all the time a lot of swap:

```
    adam@adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB:~$ free -h
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:           7.5G        5.3G        158M        1.4G        2.1G        567M
    Swap:           15G        5.2G         10G
```

My screen froze and I had once to again to do a hard reboot! It froze when I was downloading a big file of 7Gb. It often crash when I download big files, and to avoid system crash I quit a lot of apps before download. Don't know why maybe because it needs ram to download the file. If I download a 20Gb file, do I need 20Gb of RAM? Strange.

I have a laptop, so I can't had some new RAM for now.

What I am using as apps, I was using the same apps on Windows 10 and must admit I get these RAM/SWAP issues only on Linux!

I couldn't find any information on my log files, please find:

- kernellog: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b98FXDY5orcQ8R_27aK56URkC3HwoCLX/view
- syslog: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1coVhe7nGtFGDahBzpK1kZ9P8uywXDYXY/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT2**

For Opera, I installed it from the Ubuntu Software Center. I uninstalled it for now and looking .deb version. But my laptop crashed again so without using Opera...

If I use several browsers, that's because I do some PHP web dev and I sign in on different local (Nginx) websites I develop with different test users having different rights...I was doing the same on Windows 10 with the same browsers. But also, for example, I use Opera for its VPN to change easily the location and test my dev with the PHP libraries/geoip.

After the today crash, my swappiness is now at 10.

```
   adam@adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB:~$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
    10
```

I use some very cool Gnome extensions and I do appreciate this working environment, I will do my best to keep on using it and not come back to W10!

```
adam@adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 6 adam adam 4096 janv. 26 01:19 .
drwx------ 3 adam adam 4096 mars  21 15:47 ..
drwxrwxr-x 5 adam adam 4096 janv. 19 22:51 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 adam adam 4096 janv. 20 19:46 no-title-bar@jonaspoehler.de
drwxrwxr-x 3 adam adam 4096 janv. 19 23:30 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 adam adam 4096 janv. 20 00:21 workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com

adam@adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB:~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 août   5  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 janv. 19 03:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 août   5  2019 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 août   5  2019 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

My disk is an SSD, I guess I don't have to check for some bad blocks? Isn't it?

**EDIT3**

```
adam@adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB:~$ ls -al /var/crash
total 71348
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Mar 19 11:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root         4096 Jan 20 11:34 ..
-rw-r-----  1 gdm      whoopsie  3228635 Mar 19 11:45 _usr_bin_Xwayland.121.crash
-rw-r-----  1 gdm      whoopsie 27575267 Mar 19 11:44 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.crash
-rw-r-----  1 adam     whoopsie 42236551 Mar 17 14:05 _usr_bin_gnome-software.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 adam     whoopsie        0 Mar 17 14:05 _usr_bin_gnome-software.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Mar 17 14:05 _usr_bin_gnome-software.1000.uploaded
```

These files are available at:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vcNtIu0W0bK5OoTnwVrQ_-BfE5uZb7Ad

**EDIT4**

I have put back the swapiness back to 80

I have checked the memory with https://www.memtest86.com/ and hopefully it has been long but it passed successfully of all the 4/4 tests.

I have also disabled Wayland `WaylandEnable=false`.

It worked fine for 2 days, but on day 3, it crashed on out of sleep mode.

The day after I received a new 8G ram bar, but I had to wait for the delivery of the screwdriver torx t5 to be able to open my laptop! I feel very lucky, not all laptops can accept new ram bar.

[image]

It's now working fine for 3 days without any crash. Yet I did a lot of tests using a lot ram, even launching a game from Steam whereas all my usual softwares are running...and no crash.

So I think I can keep on using Ubuntu without changing my habits.

At this time:

```
adam@adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G         11G        701M        932M        3.1G        2.6G
Swap:           15G        1.8G         14G
```

**NOTE:**
When I had only 8G of ram, I launched all my usual softwares and I was swapping, I tried to connect a Bluetooth keyboard (Logitech k810) and it did not work, there was a error message on syslog of out of memory! I quit Firefox to get free ram and could connect the Bluetooth keyboard...
I feel like the Linux swap is not some new ram virtualized when that's what I expected from the swap.

Comment: Have you enabled zswap? Or installed zram? Are you actually able to boot fully?

Comment: I think it's enabled: `cat /sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled 
Y`. I don't need to compress my swap I have a lot of: 15G and can use up to 8G. I can increase the amount of swap if needed. Yes, I boot fully.

Comment: I have disabled zswap https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/enable-zswap-on-linux/ and now making some test to see if the system will crash or not...for now it's working fine and I am at 2.7G of swap used. I could not get 3 days without a system crash. Will tell you! Thanks for help :)

Comment: Status please...

Comment: What is Ubuntu 18?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It looks like you're crashing in zswap...**

```
kernel BUG at /build/linux-hwe-uR14Ux/linux-hwe-5.3.0/mm/zswap.c:1166!
```

Your BIOS is up to date at version...

```
Hardware name: LENOVO 80X7/LNVNB161216, BIOS 4MCN33WW(V2.05) 07/19/2018
```

You've enabled zswap by following the article at [this web page.](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/enable-zswap-on-linux/)

**Reverse your steps and disable zswap...**

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

remove `zswap.enabled=1`

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer

**Update #1:**

I've reviewed your log files. You have multiple issues causing your crashing problems. We took care of one, with zswap. You have at least two or three more issues.

- First, for 8G RAM, you have too many open apps/windows. You have three RAM-eating apps open, with Firefox, Opera, and Chrome. **Absolutely no reason to do that.** That also accounts for some of your high swap usage. Some apps you even have three open windows. Need to close not-recently-used apps/windows, or add more RAM.
- your snap version of Opera is killing your log files. Uninstall the snap version and install a regular .deb version.
- did you set your vm.swappiness back to 10? Or is it still at 80 (which would also account for the higher swap usage).
- you're getting a lot of I/O  errors, but it's coming from gnome-shell and sqlite. Strange. GNOME Shell errors are normally a defective GNOME Shell extension. Or maybe you've got a corrupt sql file.

Show me:

`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

`ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

**Update #2:**

- There's no getting away from it, **you need more RAM**. Add RAM in matched pairs to get the speed advantage of memory interleaving.
- With only 8G RAM, setting vm.swappiness=10 is **wrong wrong wrong**. Set it back to default of 60, or 80 like we had it before.
- And just to make sure that your 8G RAM is working properly, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.
- Opera can be downloaded from https://www.opera.com, or if you create `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list` and put `deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free #Opera` in it, you'll be able to get automatic updates, and/or use Synaptic to install it.
- And as much as I know you'll hate to do this, it's necessary, at least for testing purposes... go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable these four extensions... (and you MUST restart GNOME Shell, or reboot the system) and see if the system becomes more stable... really... do it... you have too many GNOME Shell errors... and if the system is more stable, only re-enable ONE AT A TIME until you identify the problem extension... I see at least two candidates...

---

```
dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
no-title-bar@jonaspoehler.de
user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com
```

---

**Update #3:**

I see a Wayland crash in `/var/crash`. We want to try and run without Wayland.

Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and...

Change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

To:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

Also, at login, select your username, then click on the cogwheel icon that appears, and make sure you've selected `Ubuntu`, not `Ubuntu with Wayland`.

**Update #4:**

Increased RAM to 16G and set vm.swappiness=60.

Comment: Unfortunately my system crashed yesterday, I have edited my post with more information. @heynnema

Comment: @LondonSmith See Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Please find my EDIT2! :)

Comment: @LondonSmith Please see Update #2 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: @LondonSmith Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: Available at EDIT3

Comment: @LondonSmith oh... are you intentionally running Wayland?

Comment: @heynnma, No I don't care the X server. I installed the proprio Nvidia drivers thanks to an official PPA https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-official-ppa-graphics/  Maybe selected / installed Wayland on a tutorial, I don't remember.

Comment: @LondonSmith Please see Update #3 in my answer. Comments on Update #2?

Comment: @LondonSmith It's unclear what you mean with "*No I don't care the X server*".

Comment: I mean, If I am using Wayland, it's not intentionally. But: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11`

Comment: @LondonSmith Well, do Update #2 and #3, and let's see where it takes us. Can only get better :-)

Comment: @LondonSmith Status please...

Comment: @LondonSmith Status please...

Comment: @LondonSmith Hello? Still there? Status please...

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but doing some test to check if a solution is working takes several days and I was waiting for some new ram. Thanks a million for your help :)

Comment: @LondonSmith Did you increase RAM from 8G to 16G? If so, then vm.swappiness shouldn't be 80 any more.

Comment: Yes I did, what should be the value of vm.swappiness? 10?

Comment: @LondonSmith depending on your app usage pattern, 60 is a good place to start. Move towards 50 - 10 only if swapping is slowing things down, and you wish to keep more in RAM... keep in mind that the closer you move to 10, the less file/disk buffer/cache will be available, and other things like file copies/etc may slow down. It's a balancing act, and 10 may not be the correct answer.